# Android: Room database warning cursor or database object not closed

Tags: android, android-room

I am getting this warning in my app

```
 net.sqlcipher.database.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

This does not happen always. I am not able to find out exactly what triggers it. This is happening for an update Query. I don't have any cursor that can be closed while doing Update. What could I be doing wrong. I am using Room.

Comment: Are you closing the database anywhere?

Comment: no, it is not closed explicitly